# Sonar Integration Tests Coverage not show + Selenium + Jboss +Jacoco

Tags: selenium, ant, jboss6.x, sonarqube, jacoco

I use Sonar 4.1.1, Jboss 6.x, Jacoco 0.6.4, execute tasks with Ant I am not allowed to use Maven. In an eclipse workspace, I have two projects, one is the web application another is selenium test.

I am able to get unit test and code coverage for unit test. But sonar is not able to read the integration test file created by `Jacoco`. I think there might be something wrong with the way I create `jacoco-it.exec` file so sonar can't read it. Because sonar does read my `jacoco-ut.exec` file. And I am able to have both `reportPath` and `itReportPath` to read my `jacoco-ut.exec` file with no problem. Also thinking maybe is something wrong in my build file. I did a lot of research and tried many different ways to create the `jacoco-it.exec` file, different Jacoco settings and followed different examples from sonar, jacoco, other blogs but still doesn't work. I must be missing something Help!! Thanks!!

I have VM arguments for Jboss like this

```
-javaagent:/path to jar/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/path for create/jacoco-it.exec
```

When I run selenium, the above code create a file with some data, size about 1.3MB

Here is the part of build relate to this issue

```
    <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
    <property name="sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
    <property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports" />

    <property name="sonar.jacoco.reportsPath" value="${reports.dir}/junit" />
    <property name="sonar.jacoco.itReportPath" value="${reports.dir}/jacoco-it.exec" />
    <property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${reports.dir}/jacoco-ut.exec" />

<target name="unitTest" depends="compile">
        <taskdef name="junit" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <!-- Import the JaCoCo Ant Task -->
        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <!-- Run your unit tests, adding the JaCoCo agent -->
        <jacoco:coverage destfile="reports/jacoco-ut.exec" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
            <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" forkmode="once" fork="true" dir="${basedir}" failureProperty="test.failed">
                <classpath location="${classes.dir}" />
                <classpath refid="classpath"/>
                <formatter type="plain" />
                <formatter type="xml" />
                <batchtest fork="true" todir="${reports.junit.xml.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="src">
                        <include name="**/*TestAdd.java" />
                    </fileset>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
        </jacoco:coverage>
    </target>

<target name="coverageTest" depends="compile">
        <taskdef name="junit" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <!--Run your unit tests, adding the JaCoCo agent-->
        <jacoco:coverage xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" dumponexit="true"                                                               >
            <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" forkmode="once" fork="true"  dir="${basedir}" failureProperty="test.failed">
                <classpath location="${classes.dir}"/>
                <classpath refid="classpath"/>
                <formatter type="plain" />
                <formatter type="xml" />
                <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
                <batchtest todir="${reports.junit.xml.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="../HelloAppTest/src">
                        <include name="**/answerTest.java"/>
                    </fileset>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
        </jacoco:coverage>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is, may be you are NOT attaching Jacocoagent.jar file to the "**TARGET**" (ex: JBoss / Tomcat) JVM's scope and stopping it so that it can flush the final code coverage data to the jacoco it exec file.

Once you do that (instead of using Maven/ANT's JVM scope), run your non-Unit (IT) tests and then **STOP** the target JVM.

After the target JVM is stopped, you'll get the final jacoco .exec file genreated for the IT tests. Use that file for sonar.jacoco.itReportPath variable and it'll work.

For ex: I pass/have this variable to the Tomcat's startup.sh script and while starting tomcat (target JVM), I use this variable within the Tomcat's actual start command.

```
PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS=-javaagent:tomcat/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec,append=false
```